# Asus Integrated Cards Crashing

Tags: crash, troubleshooting, asus-laptop

I bought a used ASUS notebook several months ago, and I encountered a bizarre phenomenon:  Whenever running resource intensive software it would crash.

I tried many things to test this myself, including, but not limited to, fresh installs of operating systems (LMDE, Kali Linux, and windows 7 and windows 8) but the problem persisted, It has crashed when playing video games (WOW, OpenArena) watching high def movies, and even when watching videos on Hulu.

I took the machine to a repair shop, and after 3 weeks of diagnostics they have informed me that the problem is that I'm not currently running windows 7 with the correct drivers installed (I put Kali on it to leave it with them), they also claimed that the USB 3.0 port wasn't working becasue of missing drivers, (linux kernel included USB 3 several years ago)

Has anyone experienced a crash like the photo below, and been able to resolve it? (the audio also crashes looping the previous 2 seconds over and over again, there is no keyboard response, and there is no mouse response).

In this instance it occurred while watching a movie and playing flash games online at the same time.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that looks like video memory corruption (most likely).  If it's integrated video, then you probably have bad system RAM (hence the crashing, sound looping, etc.).

Run Memtest86+ on it for 48 hours straight and see if it finds any errors.

Comment: I have already run memtest twice, the first time it crashed/froze during the memtest, then I swapped the order of RAM cards (to see if there was a bad pin in the beginning or something) and ran the test again.  The second time it completed the test without problems, and the computer seemed to crash less frequently, but then it started going again like before.

Comment: Stick one sitck it, run Memetest86+ for 48 hours.  If it passes, remove and insert other stick, run Memtest for another 48 hours.  Crashing/freezing during Memtest86+ definitely points to a hardware malfunction.

Comment: I have been running the memtests, and when I use one stick it works fine, but if I use both sticks, it crashes after about 3.5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Run [Video Memory Stress Test](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en) to see if the video RAM is damaged:

[image]

Comment: There are tens of thousands of errors in the video memory stress test, whether using one stick or two, and it doesn't matter which bay I put them in.

Comment: if you still have warranty, send it to ASUS for repair.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but I'm not sure as to why:

While testing the memory, it would only crash when running with both sticks of ram, if I tested with only one stick of ram, it didn't matter which bay it was in, or which stick of ram it was in, it stopped crashing.

IF anyone knows why, I would be very interested, (as I am considering putting in a second stick of ram that is only 2 Gb instead of 4 to increase total RAM to 6Gb)